# Delete trigger run for each deleted row when delete multi row on edit tab

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-delete

I have a trigger like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.TG_a 
ON dbo.a
FOR DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    INTO dbo.b  
    FROM deleted
END
```

When I delete multiple rows in the edit tab, there will be a problem:

> There is already object name 'b'

When the trigger looks like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.TG_a
ON dbo.a
FOR DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.b 
        SELECT * 
        FROM deleted
END
```

When I delete multiple rows in edit tab, there will be multiple duplicate values.

Problems:

- I realise that the trigger is firing for each row when I delete multiple rows on edit tab.
- If I delete multiple rows by query, the trigger will fire for all rows once
- This only happen when delete because of: can not insert, update multi row on edit tab

Question:

- I usually edit value on edit tab so I need some way to make trigger fire for all rows that are deleted on edit tab

Comment: *"I need some way to make trigger fire for all rows that are deleted on edit tab"* that *is* how triggers work... A trigger is fires ***once*** per DML operation, regardless of if that trigger effects none, one, or *many* rows.

Comment: *"When I delete multiple rows in edit tab, there will be multiple duplicate values."* The the duplicate values existed in the data you deleted, *or* the rows already existed in the table you are `INSERT`ing into.

Comment: *"When I delete multiple rows in the edit tab, there will be a problem:"* this is also an incorrect assumption; the error would occur if you deleted none, one, or many rows *if* the table `dbo.B` existed prior to the `DELETE`.

Comment: There are, in truth, multiple false assumptions/statements about how things work here. The main issues being that you assume the `SELECT...INTO` and `INSERT INTO... SELECT` are synonyms (they aren't) and that triggers fire once per row (they don't).

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful, because noone is recognizing your issue. Try https://dbfiddle.uk